# LWC Display a field based on the selected parent record

Tags: lightning-web-components, master-detail

On a new form, I have a master-detail relationship field

```
<lightning-input-field field-name='contactrel__c' onchange={handleContactChange}></lightning-input-field>
{DoNotCall}
```

I would like to be able to display "Do not call this person" if the record I chose in my master-detail relationship field has contact.DoNotCall = true

in my .js file, I have a function

```
handleContactChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);  // displays the record id of the parent contact record
    //get the record for the above recordId and verify if DoNotCall is true
    if yes { 
       this.DoNotCall = "Do not call this person"  
    } else {
       this.DoNotCall = "Call this person" 
    } 
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an attribute to store the id of the selected record.

```
selectedContactId;
```

change `handleContactChange` function to this.

```
handleContactChange(event) {
    this.selectedContactId = event.target.value;
}
```

Use the `getRecord` wired adapter to get the selected record field values. Set the value based on the result.

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$selectedContactId', fields: [ DO_NOT_CALL ] })
wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        this.DoNotCall = '';
    } else if (data) {
        if (data.DoNotCall) {
           this.DoNotCall = "Do not call this person"  
        } else {
           this.DoNotCall = "Call this person" 
        } 
    }
}
```

**Note:** You will need to import the `DO_NOT_CALL` field and `getRecord` in your at the top of the js file.

```
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import DO_NOT_CALL from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.DoNotCall';
```

[More Details about getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record)

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't using getRecord properly based on your example.  That solves it.